# Entity Framework 5 Soft Delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, soft-delete

I am trying to prevent any deletes on my database tables. Currently using Entity Framework 5. Firstly here is my code,

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var Changed = ChangeTracker.Entries();
        if (Changed != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in Changed.Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted))
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I've managed to prevent it with this way. When i use Remove method of EF its not working anymore.However, what i am trying to achieve is, when i use the remove method for the given ID, i want to set isDeleted(which is a (bit) column in all my db tables) value to false. Currently, i am lost in the documents and shared codes around the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably handle this by making entities that are soft deletable implement an interface, something like ISoftDeletable.

```
public interface ISoftDeletable
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Then extend your code above to check if the entity type implements the **ISoftDeletable** interface, if it does simply set **IsDeleted** to true.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var Changed = ChangeTracker.Entries();
        if (Changed != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in Changed.Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted))
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (entry.Entity is ISoftDeletable)
                {
                    // Set IsDeleted....
                }
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

You would then need to make sure queries for the Entities that implement ISoftDeletable filter out those that are soft deleted.

Comment: thank you so much. This makes a lot sense now. I've made it finally  !
edit:*cough* you did it.

Comment: @ArefiClayton Im looking for something simlar but with this method i persume isDeleted required to be on all the tables ?

Comment: Only tables (pocos) that need to have deletable records should implement IDeletable... those that dont wont be deletable.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul i am tryign to implment this solution so i am benjamin how would you code the update though of entry ?

Comment: You can set the value of `IsDeleted` with this: `((ISoftDeletable)entry.Entity).IsDeleted = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Building on @BenjaminPauls great answer, but using the generic `Entries<TEntity>`. In my opinion it cleans up the code and the nestling a bit.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<ISoftDeletable>())
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            // Set deleted.
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or even:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<ISoftDeletable>()
            .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            // Set deleted.
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```